# A word generalizing over inputs and outputs (of a system)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for one or more words that generalize over both 'input' and 'output'. If I had to convey this in a phrase, I would say "values that cross a system boundary".

For context, I'm looking for a clear word for a computer program I'm writing. I have a "black box" (e.g. an algorithm or a computational model). It has inputs and outputs. I need to find a good name for a programmatic construct that includes both the inputs and outputs.

Here is an example sentence: "The ____(plural noun)____ to the car efficiency algorithm are: engine cylinder count, engine displacement, vehicle weight, and vehicle miles per gallon".

Comment: Inputs + outputs = interfaces.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you. A small point, though: in context, I would say a black box has *one* interface consisting of the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Depends on your point of view.

Comment: @HotLicks Per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing), the singular 'interface' is more standard. Do you have another sense or context in which the plural is commonly accepted? Also, we would be using this site better if you supplied an answer (for "interface" or "interfaces"), below. Then these comments would not be attached to the question itself.

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned I/O. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output

Comment: @RichardKayser Your tone suggests you are really bothered here. I'm sorry. I'm not sure what to tell you. The world is subjective. You may disagree with my choice. You are free to delete your answer if you like, but that seems counter to the spirit of StackExchange. This isn't about winning and losing (e.g. if your answer gets picked or not), is it?

Comment: @RichardKayser This is certainly a debatable topic. I'm not saying my answer is best for every use or everyone. Also, I appreciate your comments and ideas and arguments for/against various other answers. And thanks for not deleting your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check ***parameters***. Though the word *parameter* is more often used in the context of *input*, there can be *output parameters* too.

> "The ***parameters*** to the car efficiency algorithm are: engine
> cylinder count, engine displacement, vehicle weight, and vehicle miles
> per gallon".

Wikipedia:

> In computer programming, a ***[parameter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming))*** is a special kind
> of variable, used in a subroutine to refer to one of the pieces of data
> provided as input to the subroutine.
>
> An **output parameter**, also
> known as an out parameter or return parameter, is a parameter used for
> output, rather than the more usual use for input.

Comment: I'm so used to thinking of *parameters* as inputs that I didn't think of the more general sense. Thanks.

Comment: *Parameters* works alright on the input side, but not so well on the output side. For example, algorithms and computational models often produce results based on the input parameters, but in my experience, one does not generally refer to these results (outputs) as parameters.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Normally however, rather than mentioning out-parameters, or even in/out parameters, it is better to simply define a **result** (separate from parameters) if an output defined.

Comment: I made an admittedly subjective call and selected "parameter" as best for my example; "variable" is very close too.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Perhaps *flow* or *stream*, as in *information flow* or *information stream*?

A *flow* or *stream* could be into or out of a "black box" (e.g., algorithm, computational model, subroutine).

From Dictionary.com:

> [*flow*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flow?s=t): an act of flowing
>   / movement in or as if in a stream / something that flows; stream.
>
> [*stream*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stream?s=t): a continuous
>   flow or succession of anything

Your example:

> "The *(information) flows* for the car efficiency algorithm are engine
>   cylinder count, engine displacement, vehicle weight, and vehicle miles
>   per gallon".
>
> "The *(information) streams* for the car efficiency algorithm are
>   engine cylinder count, engine displacement, vehicle weight, and
>   vehicle miles per gallon".

Comment: Typically, the word 'stream' in computing carries a particular meaning -- meaning that I don't want to convey in this case.

Comment: @DavidJames I get it. How about *flow*? Information (parameters, the results of other calculations, etc.) flow into a given black box, and results flow out  These could be the final results or serve as inputs into other boxes. BTW, the most obvious hypernym of inputs and outputs is *puts*.

Answer (score 1):

The term that comes to mind is ***variable***.

[WhatIs](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/variable) defines variable as:

> a value that can change, depending on conditions or on information passed to the program

Variables can change inside the program by reassigning a value. Parameters or arguments can be passed to variables.

In your example, the *car* has multiple *variables*: number of engine cylinders, engine displacement, vehicle weight, vehicle miles per gallon, etc. Irrespective of being a car these variables can change, and can effect one another.

For example a 2.0L 4 cylinder car will have lower mpg and mass when compared to 6.0L 8 cylinder car.

> "The ***variables*** to the car efficiency algorithm are: engine cylinder count, engine displacement, vehicle weight, and vehicle miles per gallon."

Comment: This usage gels nicely with statistics jargon; e.g. dependent and independent variables, per https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/types-of-variable.php

Comment: Food for thought in mathematical contexts: "The quantities appearing in the equations we classify into variables and parameters. The distinction ... is not always clear cut ... it frequently depends on the context ... Usually a model is designed to explain the relationships that exist among quantities which can be measured independently in an experiment; these are the variables of the model. ... one frequently introduces "constants" which stand for inherent properties of nature ... These are the parameters." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter#Mathematical_models

Comment: @DavidJames Parameters are a set of inputs which are taken into account to get an output. In your example you have 4 parameters you take into consideration.However these parameters consist of variables and constants. For example a parameter could be your tyre grip, the variable would be the amount of grip the tyre has. Alternatively, your parameters are usually defined, and you can compare the output by _changing_ or _varying_ one of your parameters.